# Vue child component not receiving prop from parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I have an Order form component which uses a OrderTasklistBuilder component. Note: there are nested components here. The hierarchy is as follows: OrderSingle > CreateOrderForm > OrderTasklistBuilder
The initial order is fetched when the OrderSingle is mounted and then passed down through child components.

The tasklist builder component is used like this:

`<order-tasklist-builder v-if="form.tasks.length" :initial-tasks="form.tasks" @taskAdded="handleTaskAdded" class="mb-2" />`

This works fine, but if there aren't any tasks in the listbuilder, the component will not display. This is a problem because someone might remove all of the tasks.

Now, if I remove the length check on form tasks the tasklist builder component will not display any tasks even after adding new tasks.

`<order-tasklist-builder :initial-tasks="form.tasks" @taskAdded="handleTaskAdded" class="mb-2" />`

The components are fairly large ( > 300 lines ) so if I can elaborate on something specific, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving logic previously in `mounted` function inside of CreateOrderForm component to `created` function.